# NodeJS and Github: keeping data safe

Tags: git, node.js, deployment, github, capistrano

I'm developing a web app which connects to a couple of services, for example: New Relic, Mailgun.

For New Relic, I have an API key. For Mailgun, I have a login and a password. I obviously don't want to check them into version control (and push them to Github). The repository is eventually going to be public.

I deploy with capistrano, and I have the following line in my deploy.rb at the moment:

```
set :app_environment, "PORT=3005 GA_CODE=UA-123456-1 GA_URL=myawesomedomain.com NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY=1234abc1234abc1234abc MAILGUN_USER=postmaster@myawesomedomain.com MAILGUN_PASS=321cba"
```

This then creates an upstart job for my node app with those variables specified as environment variables:

`NODE_ENV=production PORT=3005 /* more of the same */ node app.js`

Deploy.rb isn't checked into version control so it seemed like a good way to keep things safe. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this: it feels quite hackish and I'm sure there are better ways to keep my passwords safe? Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider using a config file ?
Two files actually, a config.json.example and a config.json, the first to show the available config options, the second being actually parsed but added to your .gitignore so it dont get pushed on github

Comment: I tried this. The problem is my capistrano clones from Github. I haven't looked into other ways of deploying.. without Github. I suppose this is perfectly possible? Might look into that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, and I really like using environment variables as you are. Especially because pretty much all node platform as a service hosting providers make it very easy to supply per-app environment variables.

One thing you may find useful is to use a module like [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) to enable hierarchical settings. Then you can easily have a settings.json file which is committed to the repo that has the local development credentials and then easily override it like you are now when you supply an environment variable or use argv.